# Align div relative horizontally and absolute vertically

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is align a div block relative to what's on the left (say an image might be there) but always at the bottom of the div. I would like to do it in CSS only, but if that's not possible then whatever way to do it is fine.

**EDIT**

This is how it's supposed to look if there isn't that much text

```
+---------------------+
|+---+Hello world!    |
||img|                |
|+---+[button]        |
+---------------------+
```

and if there's a lot of text

```
+---------------------+
|+---+Hello world!    |
||img|Hello world!    |
|+---+Hello world!    |
|Hello world!         |
|[button]             |
+---------------------+
```

I hope this clears up what I'm looking for. The button should always stay at the bottom of the page regardless if the text touches it. The button should also be as far to the left as possible without overlapping anything.

Comment: and a layout image of what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited it to better show what I'm looking for.

Comment: Similar to this, but I think this question may be clearer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239549/relative-parent-absolute-positioning-vertically-by-percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify two different positions for an element.
Instead you can work around this by wrapping your element with a wrapper element.
Give the wrapper position:relative.
Give the element you want to position vertically position:absolute;

http://jsfiddle.net/3hBds/

In the below example I interpreted 'relative horizontally' to mean stacking elements horizontally which I did by floating.

**Edit:**
To get your text to wrap the image, float the image.
Two examples shown. The last example is what happens if you don't clear the floated image.
Wrap your text and image with a div so the button is always pushed.

http://jsfiddle.net/apjX7/1/

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for, or maybe I misunderstood what you wrote. I made an edit to further show what I'm looking for.

Comment: This still doesn't solve that I want the button to be on the bottom of the div (that wraps around the image and the text) without overlapping the image. Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: Put another wrapper around the button and the initial wrapper.

Comment: This is really great! It might be nice to update this answer with the HTML/CSS/JS option in stack overflow so people can see the answer right away.